# update syntax error in the code any help on this

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-update

In my update query i am getting an update syntax error in the following code....

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim strup As String
    Try
        strup = "update MCA set urno=" & CInt(txtUrn.Text) & ",sname='" & txtName.Text & "',fname='" & txtFname.Text & "',CAddress='" & txtCAdd.Text & "',PAddress='" & txtPAdd.Text & "',EmailID='" & txtEid.Text & "',cmbdate=" & CInt(cmbDate.Text) & ",cmbmonth='" & cmbMonth.Text & "',cmbyear=" & CInt(cmbYear.Text) & ",Gender='" & cmbGender.Text & "',Mobile" & CLng(txtMno.Text) & ",10PSSC=" & CInt(txt10Per.Text) & ",12PHSC=" & CInt(txt12Per.Text) & ",10YSSC='" & cmb10YofPass.Text & "',12YHSC='" & cmb12YofPass.Text & "',Course='" & cmbNameofGCourse.Text & "',gper=" & CInt(txtGPer.Text) & " WHERE urno =" & (txtUrn.Text) & ";"
        Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strup, con)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Open()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Record Updated")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
strup = "update MCA set urno=" & CInt(txtUrn.Text) & ",sname='" & txtName.Text & "',fname='" & txtFname.Text & "',CAddress='" & txtCAdd.Text & "',PAddress='" & txtPAdd.Text & "',EmailID='" & txtEid.Text & "',cmbdate=" & CInt(cmbDate.Text) & ",cmbmonth='" & cmbMonth.Text & "',cmbyear=" & CInt(cmbYear.Text) & ",Gender='" & cmbGender.Text & "',Mobile=" & CLng(txtMno.Text) & ",10PSSC=" & CInt(txt10Per.Text) & ",12PHSC=" & CInt(txt12Per.Text) & ",10YSSC='" & cmb10YofPass.Text & "',12YHSC='" & cmb12YofPass.Text & "',Course='" & cmbNameofGCourse.Text & "',gper=" & CInt(txtGPer.Text) & " WHERE urno =" & (txtUrn.Text) & ";"
```

You have `"',Mobile" & CLng(txtMno.Text)` instead of `"',Mobile=" & CLng(txtMno.Text)`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works but now it throws an exception that the connection state was not closed...?

Comment: @user1897472 put `con.Open()` before executing query

Comment: tried that its still the same...? tried before command.executenonquery

Comment: @user1897472 Then remove `con.Open()`. It seems the connection is already open

Comment: as usual you were right Andrey Thanks a lot mate.. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Same as above answer and additional that on the last value that is
 `WHERE urno =" & (txtUrn.Text) & ";"` that a numeric or Text.

If it is numeric you should convert it or it is text then you should put it as
`WHERE urno ='" & (txtUrn.Text) & "';"`

This is how your Query will look like.

```
strup = "update MCA set urno=" & CInt(txtUrn.Text) & ",sname='" & txtName.Text & "',fname='" & txtFname.Text & "',CAddress='" & txtCAdd.Text & "',PAddress='" & txtPAdd.Text & "',EmailID='" & txtEid.Text & "',cmbdate=" & CInt(cmbDate.Text) & ",cmbmonth='" & cmbMonth.Text & "',cmbyear=" & CInt(cmbYear.Text) & ",Gender='" & cmbGender.Text & "',Mobile=" & CLng(txtMno.Text) & ",10PSSC=" & CInt(txt10Per.Text) & ",12PHSC=" & CInt(txt12Per.Text) & ",10YSSC='" & cmb10YofPass.Text & "',12YHSC='" & cmb12YofPass.Text & "',Course='" & cmbNameofGCourse.Text & "',gper=" & CInt(txtGPer.Text) & " WHERE urno ='" & (txtUrn.Text) & "';"
```